# How to use "what better way" to ask a rhetorical question?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to say that friendship can inspire a lot, using a rhetorical question. Is the following question correct?

> What better way to get inspired than by accompanying a good friend?

Comment: Yes that's fine.

Comment: What better way to ask a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine.  One could pick at it, suggesting that, maybe, "gain inspiration" would be better than "be inspired", or that "with the company of a good friend" would work better than "by accompanying a good friend", but those are judgment calls, and apt to be influenced by the wider "poetic voice" that's influencing your work.

As it is, you've got a pretty good grasp of the basic idea.  You can work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, that could work. The phrase as is now does not. Firstly, the

> get inspired

should be changed to

> be inspired

Since you're not really 'getting' anything --> that is quite an active verb, rather you are, more passively, being inspired.

Secondly, to

> accompany a good friend

...by extension, implies that friendship was already established. You say that you want to tell people that friendship inspires and this works with it, but I think what you are trying to say is that the creation of friendship inspires (this to me makes more sense -- again I am assuming some context here since your question is quite ambiguous). So for this part I would change it to

> make some good friends

Then the overall statement would be:

> What better way to be inspired than to make some good friends?

Comment: Accompanying a friend is a completely different activity from making friends. You're changing the meaning of his sentence, not just correcting the way it's worded.

Comment: @Barmar Quite. It should really be an edit, as this example is far more natural.